# Excel: get number of cell programatically

Tags: microsoft-excel

I’m doing this, but it doesn’t work:

`=&ROW(D(RIGHT(A21, LEN(A21)-SEARCH(" ", A21, 1))))`

I want to calculate the find number from a different cell, and append it to `D`row to get for example: `D8`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct (pun not intended) way to do what you want is

```
=INDIRECT("D" & RIGHT(A21,LEN(A21)-SEARCH(" ",A21,1)))
```

which builds the `D8` string
by concatenating the string (text literal) `"D"`
with the number you extract from cell `A21`
and then passes it to the `INDIRECT` function,
which accesses a cell based on its address as a string.

Perhaps a better way (if you always want to access Column `D`;
i.e., that’s not variable) is

```
=INDEX(D:D, RIGHT(A21,LEN(A21)-SEARCH(" ",A21,1)))
```

which gets the number from cell `A21` as you do,
but then uses it as an index into Column `D`.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this one of two ways. Take a look at the function

```
=INDIRECT(ref_text)
```

The "ref_text" can be text that refers to a cell. For example if I put:

```
=INDIRECT("A1")
```

where "A1" is text, I can reference a cell. You can piece together the text in this function using other formulas like yours in the original post.

Another way that may work for you as well is to use the function

```
=OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])
```

to which you reference a cell initially and then tell the function how many rows or columns you are away from that cell.

Comment: Thanks, `INDIRECT` did the trick! :)